# Show $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm having trouble showing that $p(x)=x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$.

What I tried: I already know the roots of $p(x)$ are $r=\pm \sqrt{2}$, so I just need to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$. Assume the contrary; then $\sqrt{2}$ must be expressible in the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$ as $\sqrt{2} = a + b\sqrt[3]{4} + 2c\sqrt[3]{2}$, with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$. I subtracted $\sqrt{2}$ from both sides and used the independence of the basis to get a nasty system of equations that I couldn't solve. I'm guessing there must be some elegant way around this.

Comment: The degree of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 4)$ is $3$ since $x^3-4$ is irreducible (it has no roots and is of degree less than 4). Hence it cannot contain a subfield of degree $2$ since $2\not | 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you know that $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and in particular $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, $x^2-2$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$ if and only if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$ contains $\sqrt{2}$. However, this cannot be the case, because clearly $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$ has degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$, so it cannot contain a degree 2 field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (by multiplicativity of degrees).

Comment: D'oh, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks.